# In the confirmation page if I click browser reload ,items are getting added in the cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding some items in the cart after adding that and click the submit button it goes to new page and it's the confirmation page.In the confirmation page if I click the browser reload button item are keep adding in to the cart.I am using Flask and Python.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/822486/detect-browser-refreshed-using-jquery

I tried it from this link and it didnt work

This is my code for the confirmation page

```
<body>
<div class="container col-md-offset-1">

    <div class="row top-space-30">

        {% if value != "" %}
        <p>You have added an items in the cart</p>            


        {% else %}
        <p>wrong check it</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

</div>
```

Once I click the browser reload I should go to the previous page or atleast the item should not get added in the cart

Comment: Someone please pour some suggestion on this

Comment: Looks like you are adding items to the cart in the confirmation page. Ideally you should add items to the cart when it is actually added and send to the server. In the confirmation page, just get the data from the server and don't rely on the data in UI objects. Hope this helps you to understand better. We don't have access to your code, so it's not possible to give you snippets.

Comment: I would post back to the same page where you add your items - if successfully added, then redirect to the confirmation page with your server side code, if not, show an error message.  That way if they refresh on the confirmation page, your items won't be added again and if they refresh on the items page, they will just get the error message again